# RowCase is manual but still can't delete account share

Tags: apex, dml, accountshare

This code here fails:

```
 List<AccountShare> existingShares = [SELECT Id 
                                      FROM AccountShare 
                                      WHERE RowCause = 'Manual' 
                                      AND AccountId 
                                      IN :accIds 
                                      AND UserOrGroupId 
                                      IN :partnerLoginUsers]; 


if(existingShares.size()>0){
        delete existingShares;
        }
```

The Error:

> first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, id does not exist

So i went to workbench found the record...it exists, it shows it's RowCause is manual and what happens when i try to delete:

| Result | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Id Does Not Exist | INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY |

i thought if the rowcause=manual it should be okay to delete, works with others but not this one. The UserOrGroupId references an active partner user who is not the record owner. But they are on the account team and so i'm guessing they have another accountshare record that exists for that which i thought shouldn't be a problem.

Then i deactivated the user, removed them from all the teams...then reactivated the user. Then i was able to delete the manual share. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to get around it?